# C# socket communication between two servers

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I have a service, which connects to the Socket Server (both are C#). The Service connects and successfully sends data to the Socket Server, but "freeze" on `socket.Receive(receivedBytes);` - line. This is happening when they are on different servers. When both (the Service and the Socket Server) are on the same machine - it works. In the Socket Server I opened the TCP port, inbound and outbound, on the service's server I opened the TCP port, inbound only. This is the code on the service side:

```
        byte[] receivedBytes = new byte[1024];
        IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.GetHostEntry(socketHost);
        IPAddress ipAddress = ipHost.AddressList[0];
        IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, socketPort);
        Socket sender = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        sender.Connect(ipEndPoint);
        byte[] forwardMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg);
        sender.Send(forwardMessage);
        int totalBytesReceived = sender.Receive(receivedBytes);
        sender.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        sender.Close();
```

What I miss? Should I do any other security configurations?

Thank you!

Comment: Apparently, with your protocol, after the server receives "forwardMessage", it's supposed to send a response. The fact that your `Receive()` doesn't return, means the server _isn't_ sending a response. At all. Why that happens depends on your protocol, of which no information whatsoever is included in your question. That this only happens when they're on different servers indicates that you don't have a framing protocol, or that you have a bug in your implementation of it. Hint: one `Send()` does not necessarily correspond to one `Receive()`.

Comment: Also, in plain C one `send` may not mean the whole message is sent, though it may be different in C#.